# Returning row and column value in a large chart if column is in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

This is for a wastewater oxygen saturation chart used in determining Biochemical Oxygen Demand values.

I want to find the intersection value returned to a cell of my choosing. But the catch is that the column values are in a range from the column farthest out value is the low number, to the previous column value being the lowest range to jump into the next column of values.

[image]

I've tried VLOOKUP, coupled with INDEX / MATCH, and I still can't seem to get a handle on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(D4:R33,MATCH(V3,C4:C33,0),MATCH(W3,D3:R3,0))
```

Do match for both axis in the index.. That's I think the part that do the job. ( :

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. Unfortunately, I get an N/A returned. I thought adding the zero at the end returns an exact match. I used the formula you posted at the top and return an N/A. Not sure how to get the top column numbers to return using the numbers in V3 and W3. So I would need the formula to return 8.77 or cell K27.

Comment: N/A is returns if there is no exact match.. ||  also.. in my file I set all the vales as numbers (not text) || I this doesn't help, I think to share your file is the best next step for troubleshooting. ( :